# How to deploy Django app such that it works on Google Cloud Standard Environment?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, django-views, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Python Django web app that does web scraping. I am using Selenium and beautiful soup. Everything works fine on the localhost. But as soon as I deploy it to Google Cloud project, on its scraping endpoint I get this error (given in screenshot) which suggests that Chrome Driver is not installed in GCP environment. Can anyone suggest how this issue can be resolved.

I am using STANDARD ENVIRONMENT with automatic scaling enabled.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWeIE.png)

I initially thought that the problem was because my library was using the GUI mode so i turned headless browsing on and GUI off, but still the problem persists.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you did to deploy your application? Sharing the "app.yaml" file would be great as well.